# Why doesn't S4 accept default arguments on methods unless it is also set on the generic

Tags: r, r-s4

I was trying to set a default argument for my S4 method but found it only works if I also set a default value to the generic function. I was hoping someone could explain why this is happening as I would have expected this to work by just providing the default argument to the particular class definition?

```
myObj <- setClass(Class = "myObj", representation = list(x = "character"))

setGeneric(name = "myMeth", def = function(object, arg1) standardGeneric("myMeth"))

setMethod(
    f = "myMeth",
    signature = "myObj",
    definition = function(object, arg1 = "hello, world") {
        print(arg1)
    }
)

foo <- myObj()
myMeth(foo)

#> Error in print(arg1) : argument "arg1" is missing, with no default
```

Compared to:

```
setGeneric(name = "myMeth", def = function(object, arg1 = "") standardGeneric("myMeth"))

setMethod(
    f = "myMeth",
    signature = "myObj",
    definition = function(object, arg1 = "hello, world") {
        print(arg1)
    }
)

foo <- myObj()
myMeth(foo)

#> [1] "hello, world"
```

Comment: I'm not sure the set-up makes much sense. You aren't using the presence or absence of `arg1` to select a method for dispatch, and you don't want to have to give it a default value in the generic,  so it's not clear why you would include it in the generic definition at all. Perhaps you want it there to allow `arg1` to be passed as an optional argument in some cases. But then you can simply use elipsis (`...`) in place of `arg1` in your generic definition. This produces the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the explanation goes like this:

- R calls the generic more or less like any other function call.  - Your generic declares that it has two arguments, `object` and `arg1`.
- The generic looks at what was passed as its arguments to figure out the signature of the appropriate method to call.
- Since your call to the generic didn't include `arg1`, you get the error message `argument "arg1" is missing, with no default`.  It never considers calling the method, because it couldn't work out the appropriate signature, so it doesn't know about the default.

@AllanCameron in his comment gave a different design that probably does what you want to do:  put `...` in the generic instead of specifying `arg1`, which you want to be optional.  Or do it as you did in your second version, with `arg1` having a default value in the generic as well as the method.

Comment: Interesting, on point 3 though I would have then expected setting `signature = "object"` in the generic function to also have solved this issue but it still persists, at least from the documentation it implies setting signature defines which variables are considered when determining what to dispatch to.